# Localisation and globalisation ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 all views

Tags: asp.net, view, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, globalization

I have an app where the user must log in before they can access their records, so far I've been able to localised (translate) the login page using exactly [this tutorial found here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hy9G30nncMM&t=1578s) but when they login the page defaults back to en-GB (which is the default language).

My question is how do I make the language selected to be the language used through out the page whilst the user is on?

in startup.cs I have this:

```
 (IServiceCollection services Method)
 services.AddLocalization(opt => { opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
        services.AddMvc(opts =>
        {
            opts.Filters.Add<SerilogLoggingActionFilter>();               
        }).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(); 
       CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
 {
    new CultureInfo("en"),
    new CultureInfo("fr")
};

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
    {
        new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
        new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
    };
        });
```

And then in the   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) method I have:

```
      app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
           
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            
        });
```

I created a partialView to allow the user to select the language, here is that partial view:

```
@{
   var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
   var cultureItems = locOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = localizer.GetString(c.Name) }).ToList();

   var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~ 
  {Context.Request.Path.Value}{Context.Request.QueryString}";
  }
 
 <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" method="post" 
 class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  @if (requestCulture != null)
  {
  <input type="hidden" name="currentCulture" value="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name"/>}
 <select name="culture" onchange="this.form.submit();"asp-   for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems"></select>
```

As u can see from the partial view, when the user selects their language it gets sent to the Home controller, 'SetLangauge' method here is that method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {

        CultureName = culture;

        Response.Cookies.Append(

            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(30) });

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

This method obviously use the 'Cookie' approach to persist the language selected, however, as I said, once the user logins, it defaults back to the 'en-GB'

all the method above works along with my resources folder, just need a way to have it working on other pages please?

Thank you - sorry about it being long but that's literally what I have based on the tutorial link as well which I have provided. Thank you for your time - I have search everywhere on here still can't get it working on other pages.

//EDITED VERSION
The login page view looks like this

```
@model PropGlobalise.Models.UserViewModel
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer localizer

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login" method="post">   

@ViewData["CurrentCulture"] //for debugging only
<div class="ml-auto mt-4"> 
<input asp-for="EmailAddress" type="email" 
placeholder="@localizer["emailAddress"]" > 
</div> <br />

<div class="ml-auto mt-4">
<input asp-for="Password" type="password" 
placeholder="@localizer["password"]"></div> <br />

<div class="ml-auto mt-4">
<a class="signInText" style="cursor: pointer;  float:right;" onclick="@(" 
window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("ForgottenPassword", "Users") + 
"' ");">@localizer["forgotPassword"]</a>

<a style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: "onclick="@(" 
window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Create", "Users") + "' 
");">@localizer["registerNewUser"]</a></div></div>
                       
<div class="gform_footer top_label">
<input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_1" 
class="gform_button button" value="@localizer["login"]">
<div>
                                   
</form>
```

In the login view this piece **@ViewData["CurrentCulture"]** shows what language the user selected from the language dropdown which works e.g. shows en for English and fr for French, the Home controller looks like this:

```
[TempData]
  public string LanguageSelected { get; set; }
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Index() 
    {
        CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;      
        LanguageSelected = currentCulture.ToString();
       
        ViewData["CurrentCulture"] = currentCulture;

        
        return View();
    }
```

I tried saving **LanguageSelected** as a TempData so it redirects to the next view with the chosen language. So when the user clicks login the nex view page they see(which is 'Records') has this  in the controller action view:

```
  public IActionResult Records()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
   CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture((LanguageSelected).ToString());
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
   CultureInfo((LanguageSelected).ToString());
        TempData.Keep();
  }
```

This seems to work i.e. the user is redirected to the next view in the language selected. but when you click between pages 'LangaugeSelected' is set back to 'null' in the controller - which is caused by TempData having sort life span. So anyway I can persist the selected language for a long time? Someone mention 'queryString' but I'm not sure how to proceed with that.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share your login view codes? Have you use the right Localisation for the content?

Comment: Hi Yes, I have the login translation works. So for example if you select French from the language dropdown, the login page IS translated to French, my problem is that when the user refresh the page or login successfully, the page goes back to default language (en-GB). So the problem is how to persist the selected language through a session?  I share some code below using TempData approach but it gets lost after a while.

Comment: I still couldn't understand what you mean about "all the method above works along with my resources folder, just need a way to have it working on other pages please?" . Do you mean if you redirect to another page, the request will not send the cookie from user bowser, so you missed language setting? Do you mean the other pages is not using resources folder?

Comment: The other pages are not using the cookie from the login page, but if you add /?culture=fr you get the page in French which shows that the resource folder is working for that page but the cookie is lost after they login?

Comment: I couldn't understand why the cookie will lose after the user login. Do you have any codes which will delete all the cookies?

Comment: No code anywhere deleting cookies, but I've been able to save the selected language in db and then display the resource language(.resx files) in all views for the user throughout  the page. It seems to work as expected perhaps not very efficient but it works for now till I figure something out.  Cheers for your responses.